# Laravel listen for whisper

Tags: reactjs, laravel, sockets, redis, laravel-echo

I want to send message from client to server via laravel-echo and save the message to database. after done some searching I understood `whisper` method can send message to redis server.

```
window.Echo.join('room').whisper('newMsg', {
   text : "Hello server. i am from client!"
});
```

but how can i listen for redis events and save them to database? or any other soluthion appreciated.

I tried `whisper` method to send data from client to server

Answer (score 0):

You should create a RedisSubscriber. You can do that using the command

```
php artisan make:command RedisSubscriber
```

As mentioned in the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redis#pubsub

At this point, inside the method `handle` you can write data into your database. For example:

```
public function handle()
{
    Redis::subscribe(['my-client-to-server-channel'], function ($message) {
        DB::table('cool_data')->insert(['msg' => $message]);
    });
}
```

You can check [this article](https://medium.com/@tthdvd/how-to-send-data-from-client-to-server-with-laravel-echo-196481675f31) if you want to go depth

Comment: yes I already read this article but it's confusing. I made a command `redis:subscribe`  and handle `Redis::psubscribe(['presence-room']` or `Redis::subscribe(['presence-room']` or any other stuff but none of them worked. can you explain me exactly what do I do?!